# JMeter - testing ASP.net application login script

Tags: asp.net, jmeter

I am using JMeter to load test ASP.net application. I am able to successfully record login functionality & further workflow,however when I try to playback the same recorded script next time or next day,the login always fails. My test plan has following elements --

HTTPRequestDefaults
HTTPCookieManager
Thread group
Recording controller

After login `GET` request, I have extracted `__VIEWSTATE` & `__EVENTVALIDATION` parameters using regular expression extractor & passed it on to subsequent request. Can someone help here ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) article ASP.NET applications can have one more protection level

> Security for ASP.NET applications in general and Sharepoint in particular can be enhanced by NTLM or Kerberos authentication.

So review [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)(s) in the recorded test plan, if it has something like `Authorization` or `WWW-Authenticate` headers - you need to work them around as well, JMeter provides [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to deal with Basic, NTLM and Kerberos authentication types.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion -  my HTTP Header message contains following parameters -

Comment: Referer        http://${host}/Dashboards/Distributor_Dashboard.aspx
Accept-Language  en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding         gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0
Accept   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8